# Does factory reset wear out UFS storage?

Tags: samsung, factory-reset

I have factory reset my tablet ten times. Will factory resetting an android device wear out Nand memory, ie UFS storage? How long are Twp and p/e cycles in ssd style nand storages?

How many factory resets can be done to a 64GB UFS?
My device's ufs status was checked in Samsung technical service. -100 output in Galaxy diagnostics application, what does it mean?

In short, does formatting damage the storage memory on mobile devices?

Answer (score 6):

A factory reset is nothing you have to worry about in terms of flash wear out.

Modern Android devices do encrypt all user data by default, even if you have not set-up a lock screen pattern/PIN/password.

If you perform a factory reset Android simply overwrites the used encryption keys and may be a quick format on older devices using Full Disk Encryption.

So for a factory reset I would expect less than a megabyte flash write operations.

The larger part of write operation may occur after the first reboot when all the per-installed apps are upgraded to their latest version. This will cause way more flash write operations than the whole factory reset process.

Comment: Thanks... In short, you say that even Google Play Store updates cause more writing!

Comment: Technically a Factory Reset may send a hardware specific command like `BLKSECDISCARD` or `BLKDISCARD` to the underlying flash storage (FTL), which may perform Erase operation on all cells mapped to the partition block device. Or it may just mark them deleted in its record (so that zeros are returned on any subsequent read operations) but actually add them to the to-be-Erased list, which would be Garbage Collected later. Additionally a Factory Reset [may overwrite](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/extras/+/refs/tags/android-13.0.0_r1/ext4_utils/wipe.cpp#62) the whole partition.